# Blender 2.81: Add hierarchy to selection

Tags: selection-tools

Organizing the objects under empties, I'm used to select the empties and all the objects under it by Ctrl+Shift+LeftMouse on the "Groups" I want to select.

With the release of 2.81 this no longer works: you can right-click on the empty and select all the objects under it ("Select Hierarchy"), but you can't *add* to the current selection this way (ie. select multiple hierarchies/groups).

Does anyone know about an easy way to select several empties and their underlying hierarchies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick workaround:

1. In the viewport Shift select any children objects form the hierarchies that you want to select.
2. Press Crtl + "Numpad +" to select upper levels of your hierarchy until you reach the parent objects.
3. Done!

Comment: nice one. I didn't know the Ctrl+ combination also worked in the Outliner. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it's gone, but you can still right click the parent object and hit "Select hierarchy"
But that won't work for de-selecting it :(

Edit: And it's quite impossible to select couple of parent object with their hierarchies.

Comment: Indeed.. Well, guess the big improvement in the outliner had to come with a couple of drawbacks in the beginning.. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a setback. I need to select multiple assemblies with all their children and move them to various collections every day. It was easy to shift/ctl click them one by one and add them in one go...now they have to be done individually. The only workaround I can think of till it is fixed is to select each of the parents by shift clicking or ctl clicking on them ....then use shift plus ] IN THE 3d VIEWPORT to select all the children (keep clicking til they are all selected as each click is one level of the hierarchy.

Comment: Sounds like a good workaround! Only.. when I do this (linux) I get an error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/blender/34/2.81/scripts/startup/bl_operators/object.py", line 217, in execute
    obj.select_set(True)
RuntimeError: Error: Object 'Apartment_Ceiling.A' can't be selected because it is not in View Layer 'RenderLayer'!


location: <unknown location>:-1

Comment: I get that error occasionally because of something to do with collections. ie the child of something you're selecting is turned off in a different collection. Is your mouse pointer in the 3D window (not the Outliner) when you use shift + ]

Answer (score 0):

In v2.90, one can first Select Hierarchy on the first group, then in the Outliner ctl-LMB on another parent and in the 3D View, Select -> Grouped -> Children, and then ctl-LMB on the parent again :-(

Answer (score 0):

Similar to James in v2.9, When you select a parent in a viewport or in the outliner.
Move your mouse to a viewport and press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>G</kbd> This will give you a selection window that lets you easily extend your selection. By children or other options.

*If you want to extend your selection keep the extend box checked.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this rough code snippet to solve exactly your problem. This code can multiselect hierachys and collections

```
#create operator class
class multiSelector(bpy.types.Operator):
bl_idname = "multi_selector.1"
bl_label = "multi select object hierachies or collection hierachies"

def execute(self, context):
    selection = bpy.context.selected_ids
    collection = False
    
    for item in selection:
        
        if str(type(item)) == "<class 'bpy_types.Collection'>":
            collection = True
            pass
        else:
            pass
        
    if collection == True:
        print("Collection true")
        
        for item in selection:
            for obj in bpy.data.collections[item.name].all_objects:
                isSelect = obj.select_get()
                if isSelect == False:
                    obj.select_set(True)
                else:
                    obj.select_set(False)
    
    else:
        sel_objects = []
        
        for item in selection:
            bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = item 
            bpy.ops.object.select_grouped(type='CHILDREN_RECURSIVE')
            sel = bpy.context.selected_objects
            
            sel_objects.append(item.name)
            for obj in sel:
                sel_objects.append(obj.name)
        
        for obj in sel_objects:
            obj = bpy.data.objects[obj]
            isSelect = obj.select_get()
            if isSelect == False:
                obj.select_set(True)
            else:
                pass
        
    return {'FINISHED'}   

# register operator and create keybinding
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(multiSelector)
  
    #add keymap for shortcuts     
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon
    if kc:
        km = kc.keymaps.new(name='Outliner', space_type= 'OUTLINER')
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new("multi_selector.1", type='Y', value='PRESS', shift=False, alt =False, ctrl=True)
        addon_keymaps.append((km,kmi))
```